# Binding TreeView children Binding not working

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, treeview

I am working on tree view that will list a few items. I would like to display a  root and their children. I have some problem when i would like to display the children  but it was the root.

```
//Model 
public class Root
    {

    public int id;
    public int? IdParent;
    public string name;

}

//Controller 

public ActionResult TreeView(int? id)
{
    var lst =_ref.Otbain().toList();
    IEnumerable<Root> resultat = lst                                                             
         .Where(x => id.HasValue ? x.IdParent == id : x.IdParent == null)
         .Select(x => new Root
         {
            Id = x.id,
            name = x.name,
            IdParent = x.IdParent,                                                                    
            HasChildren = (!x.IdParent.HasValue)
         });
      return Json(resultat, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

 @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("treeview")
        .DataTextField("name")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
         .Model(model => model
         .Id("Id")
         .HasChildren("HasChildren")
          )
.Read(read => read
// The action method which will return JSON
.Action("TreeView", "TreeviewDisplay")
)
 )

    )
```

I Except to have :

```
Root1
 Child1
 Child2
 Child2
Root2
 Child1
 Child2
 Child3
Root3
```

But actual :

```
Root1
 Root1
 Root2
 Root3
Root2
  Root1
  Root2
  Root3
Root3
```

Comment: You might want to look at the data being returned from the server. It seems all of them have `HasChildren` property set to false which is why they are rendered as root items in the tree.

Comment: I display  root but i want to diplay the child of the root

Comment: The solution final :   IEnumerable<Root> resultat = lst                                                             
         .Where(x => id.HasValue ? x.IdParent == id : x.IdParent == null)
         .Select(x => new Root
         {
            Id = x.id,
            name = x.name,
            IdParent = x.IdParent,                                                                    
            HasChildren =  lst.Where(h => h.IdParent == a.id).Count() > 0
         });
      return Json(resultat, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);